# Conectar Sybase a Codeigniter 3.1.10

Tags: php, sybase

Estoy realizando un Sistema en el Framework Codeigniter, el problema es que el SGBD que maneja la empresa es Sybase, en la documentación oficial de Codeigniter no encontre nada relacionado a Sybase, llevo días investigando y nada.

Ojala alguien puede ayudarme, de antemano gracias!

Comment: Deberias de agregar mas detalles a tu pregunta y si es posible agregar un poco de codigo aunque no funcione para que otros miembros de la comunidad entendidos en el tema puedan ayudarte con una solucion aunque no necesariamente sea exactamente a como la buscas :)